# Split Beans or Make all beans in just one project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, project

I have a software-web-project that use a lot of beans for differents things. Example Project 1 use Beans 1 and Project 2 use Beans 2 and Project 3 use beans 3, beans 2 and beans 1. So the old teammate use all the beans in just one project(Netbeans Beans for entities and sessions)

Just Like this

- All-EJB

  +---- EJB for project 1

  +---- EJB for project 2

  +---- EJB for project 3

  +---- EJB for project 4

  +---- EJB for project 5

And they add to the web-Projects this big project of EJB. All projects use the All-EJB, so I think the perfomance will just go really bad. I'm using glassfish server 3.1.2 and Java EE 6 with JSF and primefaces, I think splitting the EJB for each project will improve the perfomance, and use only the specific EJB for each project needed. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are projects 1-5 always running?

If yes, then you are unlikely to see better performance by splitting the EJB module into many, and you might actually get slightly worse startup performance since there is necessarily some (possibly negligible) per-module overhead in an EJB container.

If no (and some subset of projects 1-5 might be running), then you might see a (possibly negligible) startup performance improvement by splitting the EJB module into many if you can avoid loading the unneeded EJB modules since the EJB container will have less metadata that it needs to process.

I cannot think of a reason why there would be a performance difference at runtime (after the EJB modules have ben started), but as with all performance considerations, the only way to be sure is to measure.

Of course, there might be other maintainability benefits to splitting the EJB module.  I think these are much better reasons than performance to split the EJB module.

Comment: Thanks so I will keep the EJB in one module. If it doesn't improve the perfomance I will kept like it is.